# create 2d array with lists as entries

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to create a 2d numpy array that contains python lists as entries.
The mainprogram will append IDs to each entry. In the end I need to search for the entry with the most appended IDs. I will need these IDs later on and because of this a simple 2d array with integer entries, that just get incremented, won't solve my problem.
So my question is:
How do I create a 2d numpy array that contains python lists as entries?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#get image
image_rgb = cv2.imread('testpic.png')
#grayscale imgae
image = cv2.cvtColor(image_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#generate evalutatearray (2d array with list entrys)
evaluatelist = np.empty(image.shape)

ID = 443

evaluatelist[34,78].append(ID)
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Add a sample case so that we could get to same level of understanding as yourself? In short, add a [`mcve`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to label regions within the image?

Comment: yes, exactly. it is part of a ellipse detection algorithm. i draw lines in this 2d array and hope that the center of the ellipse is a the place where most lines cross. to detect the ellipse borders i need to know which lines were crossed...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create an empty numpy array of object type and then assign lists to array entries, you have to adapt your code as such

```
evaluatelist = np.empty(image.shape, dtype=object)
for x in xrange(evaluatelist.shape[0]):
    for y in xrange(evaluatelist.shape[1]):
        evaluatelist[x,y] = []
```

That is assuming that the array creation with image.shape works.